# node.js - images and css don't work

Tags: css, node.js, image

I'm a newbie in node.js and I just made a chat based on socket.io example.
I did a login form on the index of my application but the images and css are not working when I access to my application on localhost:3000. However, when I launch my index.html directly on my browser the css and the images are correctly loaded.

That's the tree of my application :
[Tree view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axIv2.jpg)

And that is what I see when I launch my node js server and I access to localhost:myPort:
[index.html on localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUHvO.jpg)

That the head of index.html :

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Khoya Talk</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="public/assets/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="public/assets/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Optional theme -->
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-aUGj/X2zp5rLCbBxumKTCw2Z50WgIr1vs/PFN4praOTvYXWlVyh2UtNUU0KAUhAX" crossorigin="anonymous">-->
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/css/style.css">
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you provide the code of HEAD with the imports of CSS and the src of the images in the index.html?

Comment: Are you using ExpressJS? You should set the static directory for assets or you simply have the wrong path.

Comment: how is node serving the `public` directory? also it could probably end up being an absolute path instead of a relative one `public/assets` -> `/public/assets`

Comment: @LucasCosta I edit my post.

Comment: @Michelem Yes I'm using ExpressJS and I try this in my index.js (the file which contain the nodejs server) : app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public/assets'));

Comment: @dm03514 I don't know how node serving the public directory, but I search on stackoverflow and I add the following instructions in my index.js : app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public/assets')); 
But it doesn't work

Comment: I think it should be `app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public')); ` if you call them as `href="public/assets/images/favicon.ico"` for example

Comment: @Michelem thank you it works !!! But I want to know why I have to do : app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public')); 
in my index.js 
Node.js is in the server-side and the index.html and css are in the front side no ?

Comment: Because you are telling node to serve any content inside /public as /public while before you used /public as /public/assets, so in that case the HTML must be `href="public/images/favicon.ico"`

Comment: @Michelem sorry, but I didn't pay attention it works partially, all my images and css are loaded but my favicon doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0):

Add `/` before all public and:

App.js

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

index.html

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

And make this for all path. And `src` property in images:

```
<img src="/assets/images/halftone.png">
```

Comment: when I do app.use(express.....); it doesn't work.
but when I do : app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public')); it works partially the background image set in my css file like this (background-image: url('../assets/images/navy_blue.png');) works but my favicon don't. 
For my favicon I did what you say

Answer (score 0):

When you load the page in your browser, check the developer tools / debugger to see whats happening.

If it cant find the css (or the images),  its because you need to use Express like this (in your js file):
At the top add:

```
 var express = require("express");
 var app     = express();
```

Then add folders with the content like this:

```
 app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Comment: ty, but it works partially, the background which is set in my css doesn't appear : background-image: url('../assets/images/navy_blue.png');

an image in my body appear : <img src="/assets/images/tchat.svg">

and the favicon doesn't appear : <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you have to use the / with the static directory

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/'));
```

Then in your CSS:
    background-image('img/pic.png') 
where img is the folder you store your images in, and make sure it is in the public folder.

Hope that helps.